# WAMP not showing localhost, PHP or Apache options

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp

Normally you would see the apache, PHP and other options in the WAMP manager but I only see the options (About, Refresh, Help, Language, Exit). I have checked the WAMP folder and all the files are there but they just don't show up in the WAMP manager.

Comment: Sounds like installation gone wrong. Back-up your www and mysql/data, then uninstall WAMP as admin, then install it as admin. In the meantime use `services.msc` to check whether `wampapache` and `wampmysqld` services are present in the system.

Comment: Try using **LEFT CLICK** and not the **RIGHT CLICK** there are 2 menus and they are different depending on which mouse button you click

Comment: did you installed wamp? or just copied from some folder? what do you call wamp? the software bundle: http://www.wampserver.com/en/  or just terms? win+apache+mysql+php ??

Comment: The solution that RiggsFolly gave solved the problem and thanks for all the answers.